# Why does e-cryptfs keep filling up /tmp?

Tags: printing, ecryptfs, 14.10, tmp, cups-lpd

For some stupid reason Ubuntu 14.10 is now filling up `/tmp` with files. There are millions.

`dmesg` shows me thousands of lines like this,

```
[15686.146977] ecryptfs_create: Failed to create file inlower filesystem
[15686.376336] ecryptfs_do_create: Failure to create dentry in lower fs; rc =
```

Eventually, I have to boot from a memory stick and run `rm -rf /tmp` and recreate it myself. What's the cause of this problem? I upgraded the system, it worked for a bit. Then it was giving me problems and when I rebooted I got tons of errors. Took me a while to find it, but it seems to not be a one off occurrence. Now my disk is full and I can't do anything that writes to disk because of all of these temp files.

### Update

Interestingly, all of the files in `/tmp` have the contents of a cups ppd file...

```
*PPD-Adobe: "4.3"
*% ===============================================
*% Disclaimer:  The above statement indicates
*% that this PPD was written using the Adobe PPD
*% File Format Specification 4.3, but does not
*% intend to imply approval and acceptance by
*% Adobe Systems, Inc.
*% ===============================================
*%
*% ===============================================
*% PPD for Samsung M262x 282x Series CUPS
*% For Linux Only
*% ===============================================
```

(The file is truncated here).

Further in `/var/log/cups/error_log`, I have lots of entries like this...

```
E [timestamp] Unable to create "/var/cache/cups/job.cache.N": No space left on device
E [timestamp[ Unable to create "/var/spool/cups/c00196.N": No space left on device
E [timestamp] Unable to create "/etc/cups/subscriptions.conf.N": No space left on device
E [timestamp] Unable to create "/var/cache/cups/job.cache.N": No space left on device
E [timestamp] Unable to create "/var/spool/cups/c00196.N": No space left on device
```

On further examination, I can see these are all symlinks to the same ppd file.

```
find . -not -type d -exec ls -al {} \;
./5452f859dd8ec -> /etc/cups/ppd/Samsung-M262x-282x-Series.ppd
./5452fb4f958b3 -> /etc/cups/ppd/Samsung-M262x-282x-Series.ppd
./5452fa54e4d05 -> /etc/cups/ppd/Samsung-M262x-282x-Series.ppd
./5452f4b801d88 -> /etc/cups/ppd/Samsung-M262x-282x-Series.ppd
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems this is a reported bug. Though supremely hard to discover.

- https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/system-config-printer/+bug/1156398

> This bug was fixed in the package system-config-printer - 1.5.3+20141027-0ubuntu1

And, in the changelog,

```
 o Fixed infinite loop generating millions of links in /tmp when PPD file
   requested from a print queue is not readable (LP: #1156398,
   Closes: #764253).
```